# Loading images with jQuery autocomplete

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, jquery-autocomplete

I am using the jQuery autocomplete plugin to display a list of users along with their photos from my DB. When I display the results without user images, the autocomplete is very fast. However with images, the images take some time to load and display. I understand that the images get downloaded and then gets displayed. However in facebook, the images are displayed instantaneously. I understand that facebook uses high configuration servers to return values and uses some other techniques to display images. Is there a way where-in I can store my images too in DB or somewhere else which can be accessed instantaneously? I am using web services to return values in json format.

Comment: are you storing images or links to images in DB?

Comment: As of now, I am storing links to images and then displaying them by pointing to src of img tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try loading images after text data loaded.
For example you can create results with blank images (`<img class="searchThumb" src="blank.gif"/>`) with attr `img_source` which will contain URL to real image (`<img  class="searchThumb" src="blank.gif" img_source="/real_img_url.jpg"/>`). Also add function to `open` event which will show images.

Simple example (it's just example and I didn't test it)

```
$(function() {
    function showImages(){
        $(".searchThumb").each(function(){
            $(this).arrt("src", $(this).attr("img_source"));
        });
    }
    $( "#birds" ).autocomplete({
        source: "search.php",
        minLength: 2,
        open: showImages()
    });
});
```

## UPD

```
$(function() {
    function showImages(){
        $(".searchThumb").each(function(){
            $(this).arrt("src", $(this).attr("img_source"));
        });
    }
    function formatItemFn(row,pos,count,term){
        // Here is formatting like I described before
        if (pos==count) showImages();
    }
    $( "#birds" ).autocomplete({
        source: "search.php",
        minLength: 2,
        formatItem: formatItemFn()
    });
});
```

Comment: open is not an option for autocomplete. I tried with formatResult too. But no luck.

Comment: @Ashish I just checked [jQuery UI Autocomplit page](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/) tab "Events". Autocomplete have event `open`. Description from UI docs: `Triggered when the suggestion menu is opened.` there you can find example using `open` event. And yes you right `open` not an option it's event.

Comment: I am using the jQuery autocomplete plugin and not jQuery UI autocomplete. (http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Autocomplete/autocomplete)

Comment: Ok, I thought you are using UI :) Check out my update. Maybe this will help.

Comment: Not exactly what I wanted. But still gives me a direction. Voting it as an accepted solution. Another solution would be to store image data in base64 string format in DB and render it in img element src as <img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGg..." /> Hope this would hep other users who already have images stored in DB. 

@RAMe0: Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Ashish you welcome. I don't think that using base64 is good solution... Because you response will be heavy. Facebook working like I described: first it loads items list and after that it starts to load images

Answer (score 0):

See this:

http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1862-Be-Careful-When-Including-Images-In-jQuery-Auto-Suggest.htm